# Why does scikit-learn multiply class_weight with num_classes

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, keras

Does it make a difference for keras (or scikit-learn) if our `class_weight` dictionary, used in `.fit()` for keras models and when declaring scikit-learn models, has weights that have the same ratio between classes but in larger scales?

Example:

```py
num_samples = 100
num_classes = 2
class_a_samples = 80
class_b_samples = 20

# Do we prefer this?
weight_class_a = num_samples / (num_classes * class_a_samples) # 0.625
weight_class_b = num_samples / (num_classes * class_b_samples) # 2.5

# Or this?
weight_class_a = num_samples / class_a_samples # 1,25
weight_class_b = num_samples / class_b_samples # 5
```

I know scikit-learn uses the first approach but I can't understand why multiply by `num_classes` (at least when `num_classes` = 2)

Comment: What is "class_weight"?

Comment: Forgot to mention it sorry, I mean the "class_weight" parameter that can be specified when calling `.fit()` on a keras model or when declaring a scikit-learn model